# What are the differences and similarities between the role of female “sovereignty” in Lanval and “The Wife of Bath’s Tale”?

Tags: the-canterbury-tales, geoffrey-chaucer, lais-of-marie-de-france, marie-de-france

I would like to know the specific differences and similarities and some examples for me to better understand the differences and similarities.